# How to personalize my website url and remove file extensions?

Tags: html, .htaccess, url, web

I’m planning in doing a web site for a personal project and I would like to personalize the URL but I couldn’t find how to do that.

Instead of the url being `www.mywebsite.com/example` I would like to change to `www.example.mywebsite.com`.

Another thing that I would like to do is remove the file extension, i.e.: `www.mywebsite.com/example` instead of `www.mywebsite.com/example.html`

I think that these stuff need to be done in `.htaccess` but I don’t have idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first point you can do with subdomains, that you see in your hosting account or question with technical support. The second point of the extension of the html you can do in the .htaccess as you say:

If you want to remove the .html extension from a html file for example yoursite.com/wallpaper.html to yoursite.com/wallpaper you simply have to alter the last line from the code above to match the filename:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Source: https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/